# Will an Xbox 360 bought in the US work in India?

Tags: xbox-360

Are there any issues with an Xbox 360 sent from the US to India?

I'm selling mine on eBay and I'm wondering if the guy will be able to play the games I'm sending along, and would he be able to play on Xbox Live as well? Or login to a Live account?

A friend told me that Microsoft has region-locked Xboxes and so they don't work outside the country of purchase.

Is this true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you will be able to **play** any games already purchased and/or sent along.  Xbox Live may be a problem, but as far as I understand, it's only a problem for buying new games on the marketplace, not for playing already purchased game.

Comment: Can he login to Xbox Live and download some free games? Would it work for sure?

Comment: It depends on the games: ie whether the company selling them has provided a license for India too.  As far as I know, that would probably be pretty limited.  However, there are ways around this, should one wish to search google for them.  Not that I would condone IP spoofing...

Comment: As this was answered 3 years ago. I was wondering if anything has been changed in these 3 years?