# I am planning on going out to Pakistan

Tags: xbox-360

I am planning on going out to Pakistan soon and I am wondering if I should bring my Xbox 360 for a friend that stays there,

Would the Pakistani games work on my Xbox 360?

Comment: Where does your Xbox *come* from?

Comment: Please write descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10056/18146 check this out may help

Comment: @Brian I notice you clarified the question as being about a US Xbox. Do you know the asker, or are you just guessing? (If guessing, even if it's highly likely, please don't.)

Comment: If I'm incorrect he can change it, i'm sure he'd rather have an open question with a right answer than a closed question without an answer. Its asking more about cross region play.. us->pakistan, uk->china, japan->russia its all the same on whether its region locked

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is it allowed to edit based on guess work, and no actual basis as Brian is doing? I'm not so sure.

Comment: It's not.  Guesswork gets rolled back, because it's the responsibility of the asker to provide enough details to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @fbueckert The close reason is misleading without the edit and makes the same assumptions as the edit. Feel free to change the close reason to unclear whats being asked

Comment: @Brian We don't edit questions to make them "more duplicate". The edit to say "US Xbox" is only justifiable if it's a fact of the asker's situation.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie think you misunderstood, I'm saying at present, the close reason does not make sense and should be changed to on hold and needs more information

Comment: @Brian Ah, I understand. If the asker ever speaks up to answer my question, then we can clear that up. If they just disappear though, there's no advantage to changing the close/hold reason.

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox 360 is region locked. [Play Asia has a good guide to help determine what games are playable.](http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-00-3-xbox360_compatibility_guide-49-en.html)