# Buying xBox / PS3 from US and using it in non-US region?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3

I know people have asked this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10056/will-an-xbox-360-bought-in-the-us-work-in-india) but that was like 3 years ago. So my question was if I buy a xBox / PS3 in US then:

1) Will I be able to download games here in India?
2) Will I be able to buy games(cd /DVD) and install and play it?
3) I have a [Microsoft wired controller](http://www.flipkart.com/microsoft-wired-controller-windows/p/itmdkzhyfgpm349g?pid=ACCDYH2ZFYHY5H9N), So my choice was to go for xBox 360. Will this controller work fine with the xBox?
4) Also which console is better for multi-player non-online games. So I can play it with my brother.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Hi, Danton.  Unfortunately, this question`s already been asked, as you noted.  In cases like that, we update the answer, rather than ask it again.

Comment: @fbueckert: But since it was a long time ago i decided to ask again. Anyways has anything changed in these 3 years ?

Comment: @theGreatDanton If you're worried something may have changed, post a comment on the accepted answer requesting an update.

Comment: @SaintWacko: okay will do